# Facebook Authentication Request within an Iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-authentication

I wanted to test if Facebook allows such kind of authentication requests:

```
  <iframe src="  https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=my_id&redirect_uri=my_uri&scope=email,publish_stream&type=web_server"></iframe>
```

It worked for me.
Why does it work? - **Should it work?** - what about click-jacking?
And when does Facebook block requests similar to this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-domain iframes are officially secure elements, you can't tamper with them really.

You can float a hidden div over it to intercept clicks, but there's no way to pass it to or "make" a click happen inside the iframe.